# Jupyter Notebook malformed http message from 1 content-length too long

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly

I created a notebook with Python 3 with many graphics using plotly, but when I try to save it shows me this error:

> malformed http message from 1 content-length too long in console and
>   then web browser is death.

Answer (score 4):

Being unable to save notebooks with a large amount of content has been a known [issue](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/650) in Jupyter Notebooks for a long time, unfortunately it is hard for them to fix it because the limitation is not in their side of the code but in Tornado, one of their dependencies. Hopefully it will be fixed in the future but for now there's only a few workarounds you can find in the issue.

With Plotly (and in most of the cases) I recommend clearing all cell outputs before saving, if you want to keep the plots you can save them as `json` files using python's `json` module and plotly's `to_plotly_json` method.